# Plus and minus increment script on <div value=""></div>

Tags: jquery

I am having a tough time trying to adapt my code to increment the inside `div`'s value on `button` clicks. I am using **ui semantic css** libraries for design. The display of `class="or"` is the `value=""` inside the `div`. I would like to increase it or decrease it on `button` clicks.

My attempting code looks like this:

```
<div class="ui buttons">
    <button class="ui button" value='-' onclick='javascript:process(-1)'></button>
    <div class="or" size=10 id='v' name='v' value="0"></div>
    <button class="ui positive button" value='+' onclick='javascript:process(1)'></button>
</div>
```

My unfunctional script:

```
function process(v){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').value);
    value+=v;
    document.getElementById('v').value = value;
}
```

Comment: why not using `number` input? [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number)

Answer (score 0):

If Its just matter of setting value of `div` then you should use `innerHTML` or `innerText` for `div` instead of `value`

```
document.getElementById('v').innerText = value;
```

> `value` can only be used for input controls

Comment: `innerHTML` returns the `HTML` code. It will make troubles if he put `HTML` in his `div`.

Comment: You should edit your question and add details about css too @learninghowyearspass. Also, if your css can access value, then you might want to use Input instead of div

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `value` on your `button` and in your `div`.
Use `innerText` for your `div`.

```js
function process(v){
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('v').innerText);
    value+=v;
    document.getElementById('v').innerText = value;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui buttons">
    <button class="ui button" onclick='process(-1)'>-</button>
    <div class="or" size=10 id='v' name='v'>0</div>
    <button class="ui positive button" onclick='process(1)'>+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The script works wonderful but I can't target my content in CSS now...

ui.buttons .or:before {
  
  content: ' ';
 
}

.ui.buttons .or[innerText]:before {
  content: attr(innerText);
}

Comment: Just add your class in it.

Comment: I did, apparently attr only works with custom data- types, so I can't anchor it to have it displayed as my innerText... I can't seem to find a way around it. That's why I had value="" as first...